# Swift Framework with Chromecast: include of non-modular header inside framework module

Tags: swift, frameworks, chromecast

I have found lots of suggestions on how to solve this error, but none have worked for me. I'm trying to build a framework that use the official Chromecast Framework. I get this error when I try to import Chromecast Framework:
[image: Error message in TestChromecast.h]

I have created a very simple xCode project that recreates this error [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/quv6e228pbiu7as/TestChromecast.zip?dl=0).

How do I solve this (using xCode 7.1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a tricky one, the secret is to extract all the framework contents (headers files and static library) and include it on the project.

So, let's first extract the files and add to the project all this files:

[image: Extracted Framework]

Then make sure change all the references on your GoogleCast.h file (removing the imports using the framework "<>":

[image: New references]

Now, select each header and put as a public header on Target Membership section:

[image: Target Membership]

And finally add the import on your .h file, remember put this import at the end of the file:

[image]

I create a sample project, you can downloaded here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31580788/TestChromecast.zip

Comment: You forgot to mention that you took out the <GoogleCast/...> in each file and replace it with quotes. As in #import <GoogleCast/GCKDefines.h> changed to #import "GCKDefines.h"

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a Swift project with Cocoapods, adding `use_frameworks!` inside your podfile will resolve this issue.

Don't forget to do a `pod install` after update though.

Cheers.